# How do I get the login name inside an Azure Container App written in Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, authentication, containers

I have written a Python app (using Streamlit) and deployed it as a container app in Azure. The app is protected with Azure Authentication. The app works well, but now I need to be able to obtain the logged-in user when a person runs the app (this is for Level security).  This is obviously required inside the container app.

All of this works when developing and testing on my desktop, but the moment I build and push the container into Azure, the result is different (I either get "root" or "None" returned when I run the container app).

Has anyone ever been able to get the logged-in user inside an Azure container app before?  I would appreciate any help I can get here, please.

I tried several methods.

I have tried several methods, such as

os.environ.get('USERNAME'), and even tried to run the following

command = "az account list"
output = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)

and then interrogate the resulting JSON.

All of this works when developing and testing on my desktop (returns the correct username), but the moment I build and push the container into Azure, the result is different (I either get "root" or "None" returned when I run the container app).

Has anyone ever been able to get the logged-in user inside an Azure container app before?  I would appreciate any help I can get here, please.